# Is a function a digraph?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

If I recall correctly, a function is a set of $2$-tuples with some properties, which is itself a digraph if we let the set of nodes be the union of the domain and image of the function. Is this true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is true.

In fact any binary relation could be considered as a digraph. For example  the relation   $$ R = \text {  { (1,2),(1,3),(3,5), (1,5)}}$$ which is not a function could  also be considered as a digraph.